# Artemis mqtt client interceptor: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: interceptor, broker, activemq-artemis

I want to intercept message send by a mqtt client to artemis broker. 
I am following the example "interceptor-client-mqtt". 
My problem is that I am always getting an error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SimpleMQTTInterceptor". 
My question is where should I put the interceptor class so that the broker could find it? 
Should I put only the class of the interceptor, or should I put a jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your interceptor class in a jar in the broker's "lib" directory.